# Change background color of the button without changing its style

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am stucked in a problem developing an android App.
When the user clicks in a Button, I need to change the background colour of this button. But I need to do in a way that doesn't affects the style, mainly the shapes.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You need to accept an answer if you find it working for you.You know SO rules right?

Answer (score 1):

Okay as you have said *without changing its style*, i think here's what you want,

1.you might be interested in color filters like this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));
```

You use different values according to your required colour.If you want to know the constant values of colours, you can refer [the documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

2.you can programmatically set the shade of the entire button using the `PorterDuff multiply mode`. This will change the button colour rather than just the tint.

For example for a red shaded button

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

For a green shaded button

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

And so on.What it actually does is, it works by multiplying the current button colour value by your colour value.

3.You can also use an online tool like [this Android Button Maker](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) to customize your button  and use `android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"` in your layout(inside the `<Button>` tag) to define the customized button.

Now there are many more ways too to achieve what you want but i think these are some easy and quick fixes you can use.Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.Please accept this as a correct answer so that people who come over here can see this is the right answer.Also if the answer helped you then please upvote it.For accepting the answer just click on the "right mark" to the left of this answer.To upvote just click on the "up arrow".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton1);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(color.Green);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post some code? edit you question and add some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btn.setBackgroundResource(color.lightblue);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I've already tried it. But it didn't work for me =/.
But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of changing a buttons background is using a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). This is a xml file where different drawables for the background of the button for different states are defined. An Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize="true"
    <item android:drawable="@drawabel/normal"/> // Drawable in normal state
    <item android:drawabel="@drawable/pressed"/ android:state_pressed="true"> //Drawabel when pressed
</selector>
```

Just use `android:background="@drawable/background.xml"` in the buttons xml or `setBackground(R.drawable.background)`. The framework will do the work for you.